# Remote access to a Printer - Static IP

Tags: wireless-router, printing

On a remote location I only have the following setup:

1. DLink - Wireless Router (Internet with static IP)
2. Wireless Printer
3. DVR Security system

The DVR is running on port 80. So when I log on to http://static-ip-address, I can see the DVR interface and can see the camera streaming. Now, I want to connect a printer to the router for remote access. How can I access this printer (connected to router) from any remote location?

Comment: Does this router has VPN server capabilities?

Comment: Yes, D-link DSL-2750u is the router and printer is wireless HP Laserjet Pro MFP m132nw.